# Are there any projects which integrate couchdbkit into djangos auth system?

Tags: django, authentication, couchdbkit

I'd like to use couchdbkit with django but I noticed that the built-in auth system complains that the site is **ImproperlyConfigured**. It seems as if I **haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet.**

I suppose the obvious question is *did I overlook something*? Is it already supported?

If it's not supported are there any projects which have already tackled this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to write a [Django custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend), which is what most seem to have done in this situation.

There is also an attempt to provide CouchDB backed **auth**, **session** and **cache** storage in [django-couchdb-utils](https://github.com/theju/django-couchdb-utils), although I have no experience with this module myself.

And don't forget that you can use multiple databases, keeping **auth** and **sessions** in one of Django's natively supported (SQL) databases while using CouchDB for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [set the database ENGINE setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#engine) in the django settings file.